# Input type number adding 10 to value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just found a weird behaviour in the simplest code ever and I'm wondering why this is happening.

I have 3 `inputs` (a, b, c) of type `number` and whenever they change I store the value with jQuery in a global variable (one variable for each input). Then I call a function that calculates the average of the 3 variables `(a + b) / c`. When I `console.log` the variables and the total, it is returning `((a + 10) + b) /c`. Somehow it is adding 10 only to the first variable and I have no idea why.

```js
number_a = 0;
number_b = 0;
number_c = 0;
$('#a').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  number_a = $(this).val();
  calculate();
});
$('#b').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  number_b = $(this).val();
  calculate();
});
$('#c').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  number_c = $(this).val();
  calculate();
});
function calculate() {
  var total = 0;
 if (number_c) {
  total = (number_a + number_b) / number_c;
 } else {
  total = (number_a + number_b) / 1;
 }
  console.log(number_a, number_b, number_c);
  console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="a" placeholder="a" />
<input type="number" id="b" placeholder="b" />
<input type="number" id="c" placeholder="c" />
```

I know I can solve this using `parseInt()` with the value i get from the inputs as they are strings but It's weird It only happens with the `a` input and exactly `10` everytime.

Do you guys know why this is happening?

Comment: You've already answered your own question. use `parseInt`.

Comment: The question is not how to solve it. The question is why this is happening?

Comment: `number_a + number_b` is concatenating the two strings. `number_a` and `number_b` are both strings if you don't use `parseInt`.

Comment: If you try out your own A,B,C with value `1,2,3` and noticed that the `total` you got is **4** instead of **1**. you will noticed that `(number_a + number_b)` gives you **12**

Answer (score -1):

Use parseInt() as you said otherwise the input values will be treated as strings.

```
    $('#a').bind('input propertychange', function() {
      number_a = parseInt($(this).val());
// call the calculation function
        calculate();
       });
```